# Optical properties of metal-dielectric-metal microcavities

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, dielectric, metals, antennas

I would like to figure out the optical properties of metal-dielectric-metal microcavities, used in the fabrication of micro patch antenna.

The paper that I'm reading is [this one](https://doi.org/10.1364/OE.18.013886). Now the specific questions:

1. How is the incoming electromagnetic field directed perpendicular to the metallic patch confined under the patch itself? I suppose that the reason should be the light funneling phenomena [here described](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.107.093902), but I'm not so sure.
2. Once the field is confined under the patch only the "component" with adequate frequency remains trapped: this is due to the dimension of the patch but also to the impedance mismatch that should be the origin of the guided mode. How does it happen? What is the behaviour of the light near the edges of the patch?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.